# Nginx server to revrse proxy or load balance

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

I am trying to use nginx in front of apache.

**Apache1: http://192.168.0.11:81**

**Apache2: http://192.168.0.22:81**

And my nginx running in **http://192.168.0.333:80**

I have ip range from

**192.168.0.101-120 : Team1**

**192.168.0.121-140 : Team2**

**192.168.0.141-145 : Team3**

Now i want to use nginx to load balance as Team1 will always get the website from Apache1 and Team2-3 will get always from Apache2.

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the ngx_http_geo_module.

Like

```
 geo $upstream {
      192.168.0.101/32 apache1;
      ...              apache1;
      192.168.0.120/32 apache1;

      192.168.0.121/32 apache2;
     ...
 }

 upstream apache1 {
    server 192.168.0.11:81;
 }

 server {
    server_name website;
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://$upstream;
    }
 }
```

and so on.

Comment: 14952#0: *1 invalid URL prefix in "http://",


for apache2 @drookie